# Configuring the Spartan Refactoring plug-in for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-refactoring

I'm using the new Spartan Refactoring plug-in (from [www.spartan.org.il](https://www.spartan.org.il)) for automatic refactoring of my Java code. I really like the changes the plug-in offers, however there's one change ("Rename return variable of ... to $") I'm not really comfortable with.

Is there a way to control the types of refactoring available by the plug-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in version 2.3, you can configure the plug-in by going in Eclipse to `Preferences->Java->Spartanization`. You can change the plug-in's general settings, as well as control which refactorings will be made.

As for your question - you can simply switch off this spartanization rule by selecting "Disabled" next to the "**Rename return variable to $**" setting.

[image: Spartan Refactoring Eclipse preferences page]